# stringifying inline assembly

Tags: gcc, arm

How can I use integer parameters in the inline assembly? I have the following function parameters:

`unsigned int __MRC(uint32 coproc, uint32 opcode1, uint32 CRn, uint32 CRm, uint32 opcode2)`

I have moved CRn CRm to r0 and r1 by

```
register unsigned int r0 asm("r0") = (unsigned int) (CRn);

register unsigned int r1 asm("r1") = (unsigned int) (CRm);
```

and I now want to write it in form:

`__asm__(" MRC ...  ");`

this is the format:

```
MRC <copr>, <op1>, Rd, CRn, CRm{, <op2>}
```

Comment: You just add the **numeric** as a string.  Ie, the numeric `15` is the ASCII text **15**.  The ASCII is passed to the assembler.  If you want to use a *define*, you can use the regular *stringify* solutions with string pasting, to make your `asm(...)` text.  The other solution is to use the `I` specifier; but this may not work for you case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, I think the answer is to use [GCC Extended ASM](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) functionality. You can avoid the `register unsigned int ... asm("r*") ...` code lines and just write an inline assembly statement with extended ASM syntax.

About the fact that you need to expand some constants, maybe your best bet is to use a combination of preprocessor stringification, inline ASM and [compound statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).
Something like the following, where all the parameters are constants:

```
#define MRC(coproc, opcode1, CRn, CRm, opcode2)\
  ({unsigned int rd; __asm__(\
    "MRC p" #coproc ", " #opcode1 ", %0, c" #CRn ", c" #CRm ", " #opcode2 \
    :"=r"(rd)); rd; })

unsigned int foo(void) {
  // expands to something like:
  // MRC p15, 0, r0, c0, c0, 0
  return MRC(15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: if i pass coproc=15 i want my assembly instruction to be MRC 15,<op1>, Rd, CRn, CRm{, <op2>

Comment: I added an example to my answer that should take care of it.